# Searching for String in Array of Strings []

Tags: java, arrays, string, search, java.util.scanner

I have developed a console application to add and search for names using a looping menu. The application works fine other than my searching for names method, where it returns saying the string was found, from 1-49 before going back to the start of the menu.

```
Enter name to search: 
rog
Name found at location: 0
...
Name found at location: 49
Enter the number of the menu option you would like to select
```

my searchArray method:

```
private static void searchArray(String[] nameList, String target) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nameList.length; i++){
        if (nameList[i].equals(target)) {
            System.out.println("Name found at location: " + i);
            }
        else {
            System.out.println("Sorry, name not found");
            }
        }
    }
```

which is invoked from this portion of my inputmenuChoice() void:

```
else if (menuChoice == 2) {
        System.out.println("Enter name to search: ");

        if (menuScanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String username = menuScanner.nextLine();
            searchArray(nameList,username);
            }
        }
```

Comment: How do you populate the `nameList` array?

Comment: To avoid spamming your console, you should return bool and use that result to print whether it is found or not. Simple if found return true and return false at the end of the method will do

Comment: Just curious, you say you developed a console application to **add** and search for names... How exactly are you adding strings to a string[], which is already of a definite size?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

In my answer I added a boolean to check and make sure that you did find an instance of the target, Also an occ variables that keeps count of how many times you find the target! Hope it works for you!

```
private static void searchArray(String[] nameList, String target) {
    //Boolean to see if the name was found, int to keep track of how many occurances 
    boolean wasNameFound = false;
    int occ = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < nameList.length; i++) {
        if (nameList[i].toLowerCase().equals(target.toLowerCase())) {
            System.out.println(target+" Found at index: " + i);
            wasNameFound = true;
            occ += 1;

        } else if (!wasNameFound && (i == nameList.length)){
            System.out.println("Sorry, name not found");
        }
    }

    //Tell user how many occurances of target were found
    if (wasNameFound) {
        System.out.println (target+" Was found " + occ+ " times");
    }
}
```

Comment: And what if there is more than one of the same name within the Array? Perhaps the names are not unique within the String Array. This answer also does not explain why every element within the **nameList** array is equal to the supplied name withn the **target** string variable.

Comment: @DevilsHnd Updated!

Answer (score 0):

To print out all occurrences of the name:

```
private static void searchArray(String[] nameList, String target) {
  boolean isFound = false;
  for (int i = 0; i < nameList.length; i++){
    if (nameList[i].equals(target)) {
        System.out.println("Name found at location: " + i);
        isFound=true;
    }

  }
  if(isFound)
     System.out.println("Sorry, name not found!"); 
}
```

And if you use a return statement, you don't need the else statement. Just say "name not found" at the end of the method, because you will only reach that position if `isFound` is false (i.e. you didn't find the name).

Comment: And what if there is more than one of the same name within the Array? Perhaps the names are not unique within the String Array. This answer also does not explain why every element within the nameList array is equal to the supplied name within the target string variable.

Comment: Oh.... I was unclear as to what the question was. I will edit my answer

Comment: Don't worry about that Luke...but do keep in mind that perhaps, for testing purposes, the OP wants to display all that text in console for the moment.

Comment: does OP want to display all locations the name is found at, and the problem he is encountering that it is saying the name IS at all locations?

Comment: That's how I read it bud. To me it looks like @MickMnemonic hit it on the nail.

Comment: Ah.... so you think that something is just wrong with the `nameList` he is passing in? As in the names aren't unique?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151104/discussion-between-luke-thistlethwaite-and-devilshnd).

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to display all possible matches, you probably would want to do a case-insensitive search using the `regex.Pattern`, then display all possible matches.

Assuming you're using a list of names, you can do something like this:

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

// Some code to insert names

// In your search method
for (String name : names) {
    if (Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(criteria), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(name).find()) {
        System.out.println(String.format("Found `%s` as a possible match", name));
    }
}
```